# "play war yabe -o yabeApp --zip" doesn't work on Debian 6

Tags: playframework, debian, war

My problem: I try to "war" a play! framework app under Debian6:

In a shell, I use: (i am under debian6 without any serverx)

```
play war yabe -o yabeApp --zip
```

and play say that all is ok

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
16:42:03,976 INFO  ~ Starting /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
16:42:04,523 INFO  ~ Precompiling ...
16:42:09,598 INFO  ~ Done.
~ Packaging current version of the framework and the application to /xxxxxxxxxxxx
~ Done !
~
~ You can now load /xxxxxxxx/yabeApp as a standard WAR into your servlet container
~ You can't use play standard commands to run/stop/debug the WAR application...
~ ... just use your servlet container commands instead
~
~ Have fun!
~
```

ok nice!

I try to deploy it under tomcat6, and FAIL...

I look up on my yabeApp.war
it seem to have a valid WEB-INF/ folder
but infact,  under WEB-INF/application/ folder, there is nothing

and normaly we expect it contains our play! application :

```
app
conf
lib
public
...
```

so what append???

Anyone have the same problem?

PS 1: 
I make my war under windows7 without any problem and I can deploy the war under the same tomcat6 (Debian) and everything is ok...

PS 2:
I can use

```
   play test yabe
```

and it works on http://myServerIp:9000/
so this is not a right permission or a framework problem...
so what append???

My final goal is to build my app on jenkins, and deploy it to my tomcat6 (on the same server) and not on a dev'PC...

[info]
server: Debian6
Java :

```
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.10) (6b18-1.8.10-0+squeeze2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Python : 2.6.6

user : tomcat6
play framework 1.2.4

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my windows 2008 server where I successfully executed "play war" but there were nothing under application folder. After some research, I found this would happen when you put your project inside a hidden folder. Please refer to [War-command fails when the play application is a descendant of a hidden directory](http://goo.gl/nfWzU)

After I moved it to a non-hidden folder, play war works just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my a few times. I think TomCat is trying to 'deploy' the project while the copy action was not yet completed.

My solution is to stop TomCat while copying the .war file. After the copy is successful I start the TomCat again and everything works as expected.